# How to limit number of results returned by boolean query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, limit

I have a boolean query:

```
FilterBuilder filter= FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(fb1).must(fb2);
```

My requirement is to limit the number of results returned by this query.
[Limit Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-limit-filter.html) in elastic search cannot used for bool queries.

Suppose my query would match 100 000 documents in the index and I need only 20 results to be returned. When I use [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) approach for paging, it is actually fetching the total result count but only returning the specified number of documents. Due to performance concern, I am looking for an option where in we can break after finding 20 results instead of fetching the total result count

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Do you effectively want the first 20 results it finds, disregarding any sorting or scoring it would otherwise do?

Comment: Yes..For now we are not bothered about the sorting

Comment: If you use a scan and scroll search [link] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html), it doesn't bother with the sorting and scoring the results. It'll still work out all the ones that match, but it should be a bit lighter than just asking for a page of 20. Something to note is that the size you set for it is the number of hits per shard to return, so you want to divide your 20 by your number of shards.